# jquery animate color working only once on scolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-color

```
    $(window).scroll(function() 
{
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 900px)').matches)
    {
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
        {
            $('#upper_bar_desktop').animate({"background-color": "#ffffff" , "color": "#000000"}, 1200 );
        }

        else{
            $("#upper_bar_desktop").animate({"background-color": "initial" , "color": "#ffffff"}, 1200 );
        }
     }
 });
```

I have written this code to change the background color and font color of my upper bar on scrolling down, it does work perfectly on scrolling once but when I go back up again it does not perform the animation.

thank for the hekp

Answer (score 1):

Change initial to whatever the color was. #000000 for example.

jQuery can't animate to initial.

Also I'd recommend using classes.

```
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
    {
        $('#upper_bar_desktop').addClass('fixed'); 
    }

    else{
        $('#upper_bar_desktop').removeClass('fixed'); 
    }
```

Then you animate using CSS transition only.

```
#upper_bar_desktop{
  transition:1s;
}

#upper_bar_desktop.fixed{
  background:#fffff;
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: actually I have a photo in the background so that is why I want to set it to initial, can I go back to initial background by using classes as you suggested.